# Express session does not persist session in Graphql over Docker

Tags: docker, express, graphql, express-session, typeorm

I use graphql-yoga to create my graphql api, the express-session config is this:

```
session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    client: redis as any,
    prefix: redisSessionPrefix
  }),
  name: "qid",
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET as string,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production", // Only works with https
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 7 days
  }
})
```

Complete code [here](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/TeViEPE/blob/master/server/src/startServer.ts).

Then, if any user wants to log in, the session is saved like this:

```
session.userId = user.id;
```

The `user.id` is from an ORM called TypeORM, only find a user by the email, and I put the id of that user in the `session.userId`. Complete code [here](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/TeViEPE/blob/master/server/src/modules/user/login/resolvers.ts).

And then, if I want to check if a user is logged in or not, I use the Query:

```
User.findOne({ where: { id: session.userId } })
```

That previous code only execute the Entity from TypeORM called User, which only find what user has the `session.userId`. But that `session.userId` is undefined... Complete code [here](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/TeViEPE/blob/master/server/src/modules/user/me/resolvers.ts)

Someone know why?

These are the docker configs that I use for development.

[Dockerfile.dev](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/TeViEPE/blob/master/server/Dockerfile.dev)
[Docker-compose.dev.yml](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/TeViEPE/blob/master/server/docker-compose.dev.yml)

If someone need the 100% complete code, [here](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/TeViEPE/tree/master/server) you can find it and you can run it with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build` within the server folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone want to know, Ben Awad from [Twitter](https://twitter.com/benawad97) helped me, the solution was to add in the graphql-playground `request.credentials: include`, and that's it :)

[image]

Comment: Came here from a Ben Awad boilerplate!